Pip isn't installing anything at all
Note: I do not use Python as my main programming language, my main is C++. The reason I need pip and python is to install some personal applications which do not come with embedded python.

I don't know how to explain this, so I'll just show you the console.
PS C:\Users\Asad_> pip install --upgrade requests // any package can be used here for me, nothing installs
Collecting requests
  Using cached requests-2.32.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.6 kB)
Collecting charset-normalizer<4,>=2 (from requests)
  Using cached charset_normalizer-3.3.2-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (34 kB)
Collecting idna<4,>=2.5 (from requests)
  Using cached idna-3.8-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.9 kB)
Collecting urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 (from requests)
  Using cached urllib3-2.2.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.4 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests)
  Using cached certifi-2024.7.4-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
Using cached requests-2.32.3-py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
Using cached certifi-2024.7.4-py3-none-any.whl (162 kB)
Using cached charset_normalizer-3.3.2-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (100 kB)
Using cached idna-3.8-py3-none-any.whl (66 kB)
Using cached urllib3-2.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (121 kB)
Installing collected packages: urllib3, idna, charset-normalizer, certifi, requests
Successfully installed certifi-2024.7.4 charset-normalizer-3.3.2 idna-3.8 requests-2.32.3 urllib3-2.2.2

It appears to succeed, however:
PS C:\Users\Asad_> pip list
Package Version
------- -------
pip     24.2

As you can see, pip, Python's package manager says that the package(In this case, requests, but any package wouldn't install) got successfully installed, but when using the command pip list, it doesn't show anything.
I did already try:

python -m pip install requests
python3 -m pip install requests
python -m pip install --upgrade requests
python3 -m pip install --upgrade requests
pip3 install --upgrade requests
pip install --upgrade requests
using a Conda environment

How I installed python:

I downloaded python 3.12.5's installer from (the official webpage)[https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3125/]
This activated the python, the pip and the py command.
However, when I entered python3 or pip3, I got forwarded to the Python 3.12.5 Microsoft Store Page, and I downloaded it from there too, which activated the mentioned commands.

System specifications(I don't know if this helps):

OS: Windows 10 Pro V22H2
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 5600G
GPU: NViDIA RTX 4060 8GB
RAM DDR4 64GB (48 available, rest goes to unified CUDA VRAM).


since you tried python3 -m pip install requests did you test that via python3 -m pip list?

What is the output of echo $(get-command python).path, echo $(get-command pip).path and python -m site and pip --version (include the printed path as well as the version for this last one)?

@JonSG I did, same output. Only pip V24.2.

@Dunes Since it was quite a bit of output, I uploaded a paste on Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/vPDgu8Uk. The password is "StackoverflowProblem" :)

Found out where the problem was. Windows has a huge problem with file links, and having Pip installed on another drive than the drive where Python is installed will cause this error. I fixed it by deleting everything that was using embedded Python, then Python, Pip and Py themselves, and then re-installing everything on the drive where my file link to Pip packages was. I don't know why this works, but I know that it does work.
